# I want to develop a GUI with pyqt

Tags: ros, pyqt, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello All,

I saw the threads that the people post about pyqt, and I though maybe my question will be different and I will get the accurate answer that I want..

So now I already created a GUI with pyqt which takes data from the robot's camera and display it on the screen. Now, I want to display some information about the robot on the screen as well and I want to control him... I found some code which is written in ROS and I just want to create a GUI for it to display the information on the screen and  I am going to add some other stuff.. the question here "is it ok to you pyqt?" or shall I look up for another GUI library ??

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9621/i-want-to-develop-a-gui-with-pyqt/) by [Shamma](https://answers.ros.org/users/376/shamma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're free to use whatever software you like.  Keep in mind that PyQt is GPL, which places restrictions on the software you can use with it.  An alternative is PySide, which recently reached 1.0 status.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1